# Must of referencing of third-party libs which used in a class library which is referenced by Windows Store App project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, sharpdx

There are 2 projects in the VS2012 solution:

1. Windows Store App;
2. Class Library (for Windows Store App);

1st project has reference on 2nd project.
2nd project has reference for third party libraries (in my case it is SharpDX libs).

On build there are 2 errors:

> **Error 1** Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'SharpDX.dll'
> {1st project path}
>
> **Error 2** Type universe cannot resolve assembly: SharpDX,
> Version=2.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.

If I add to 1st project reference to the SharpDX.dll lib, then there are no errors.

But why I must ref lib in a project where lib is not used?

Is it some WinRT feature or a bug?

There is some irritation about such behavior of VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

If you use classes from your class library which use SharpDX classes, then compiler of main assembly must know what this classes are, so it needs reference to SharpDX. It's common .net behavior.